# How to set Varnish to run on port 80. Malfunction of DAEMON_OPTS set in /etc/default/varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, systemd, apache2.4, ubuntu-15.04

I have installed varnish and fallowed the exact instruction for setting it up, however, it is not working as expected.

My /etc/default/varnish setup is:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:1234 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

My /etc/varnish/default.vlc setup is

```
backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

My apache port.conf setup is:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I am running ubuntu 15.04 with Apache 2.4.10. When I start varnish and check the process i get the fallowing:

```
0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

Seems like neither of the Listen address or the Management interface work as set in /etc/varnish/default.vcl. None of my virtual machines work as a result. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok. Problem solved. First do

```
sudo grep -R 'ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd' /etc/
```

so you can actually find the other place where daemon options for Varnish are set (in my case it was /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/varnish.service). Open file in vim,nano or whatever and  set "ExecStart" in that file as fallows:

```
-a :[same as /etc/default/varnish]80 -T localhost:[same as /etc/default/varnish]1234 -f [same as /etc/default/varnish ]/etc/varnish/default.vcl -S [same as /etc/default/varnish ]/etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

Save and exit. After that do:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart varnish.service
```

And then we are done. Nothing like the official tutorial. Apparently it is old.

[`Full explanation of the problem here`](http://deshack.net/how-to-varnish-listen-port-80-systemd/)

Comment: Hello ! Thank you very much, you saved me !

Comment: I am glad that I could help :)

Comment: `systemctl restart varnish.service` did it for me. The tutorial uses `reload` which I think is not enough

Answer (score 4):

You can change the varnish default port to 80 by using below steps:

1. Open a file on path: `sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service`
2. Update your default:

   `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T :6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m`
3. Run below commands:

   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   sudo service varnish restart`

Comment: /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service will be a system-owned file that is liable to be replaced when you upgrade the varnish package. Better is to use systemd's notion of 'overrides'. This is most easily accomplished using 'systemctl edit varnish.service'... you'll end up with a file /etc/systemd/system/overrides.d/varnish.service (IIRC). You can see the full config for a service using 'systemctl cat varnish.service', which shows which files make up a service.